# Node.js roles authorization using Connect Roles

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I have been following Connect roles `https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/connect-roles` 
for authorization in my node js application every thing is coming through except this 
This is what documented in above link

```
user.can(action) and user.is(action)

Inside the views of an express application you may use user.can and user.is
```

which are equivallent to req.user.can and req.user.is

```
e.g.

<% if (user.can('impersonate')) { %>
  <button id="impersonate">Impersonate</button>
<% } %>
```

I tried to use it but i am very much confused because in my view (my html page) how can i check for specific role. Do i have to call service for checking back in the server. Because i cannot use directly like in my app.js file as this

```
var user = require('connect-roles');
user.use('access private page', function (req) {
  if (req.user.role ==== 'moderator') {
    return true;
  }});
app.get('/private', user.can('access private page'), function (req, res) {
  res.render('private');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jade it is as easy as:

```
if userCan('do something')
   button#special Do Something
```